# How to show the battery percentage in the button using PyQt5 and psutil

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt

As i'm trying to show the battery percentage in the button text.
I have imported the package like GUI (PyQt) and psutil package to get the system information. When i try to print the battery status can able to show in the console. But when i try to show inside the PyQt button i'm getting error.

```
import sys
import psutil
battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
print(battery.percent)




class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 simple window - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480

        self.initUI()
        self.battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        #------>psutil.sensors_battery() 
        button = QPushButton(psutil.sensors_battery(), self)
        button.setToolTip('This is an example button')
        button.move(100, 70)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Below is error code

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/PY3/helloworld.py", line 45, in <module>
    ex = App()
  File "F:/PY3/helloworld.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.initUI()
  File "F:/PY3/helloworld.py", line 37, in initUI
    button = QPushButton(psutil.sensors_battery(), self)
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QPushButton(parent: QWidget = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'sbattery'
  QPushButton(str, parent: QWidget = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'sbattery'
  QPushButton(QIcon, str, parent: QWidget = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'sbattery'
```

So how can set the battery percentage in the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [psutils' documentation](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.sensors_battery):

> psutil.sensors_battery()
>
> Return battery status information **as a named
>   tuple** including the following values. [...]
>
> - percent: battery power left as a percentage.

(emphasis mine)

So, you can access your value with:

```
battery_status = psutil.sensors_battery()
percents_left = battery_status.percent
```

If `QPushButton` needs a string as first parameter, you can then do:

```
button = QPushButton(str(percents_left), self)
```

Or, all in one line:

```
button = QPushButton(str(psutil.sensors_battery().percent), self)
```

Comment: Worked, so need to convert into string :)